# Failed to fetch updates, Too few items to process when trying to update from AppCenter

Tags: updates, appcenter, repositories

I updated my packages with Synaptic, and when I open the AppCenter i first get a "Failed to fetch updates" error message. As I understand from the other errors messages, this has something to do with faulty repositories. Here are mine :

```
W: Le dépôt http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki Release n'a pas de fichier Release.
W: Les données depuis un tel dépôt ne peuvent être authentifiées et sont donc potentiellement dangereuses à utiliser.
W: Voir les pages de manuel d'apt-secure(8) pour la création des dépôts et les détails de configuration d'un utilisateur.
W: Le dépôt http://ppa.launchpad.net/moka/stable/ubuntu xenial Release n'a pas de fichier Release.
W: Les données depuis un tel dépôt ne peuvent être authentifiées et sont donc potentiellement dangereuses à utiliser.
W: Voir les pages de manuel d'apt-secure(8) pour la création des dépôts et les détails de configuration d'un utilisateur.
W: Le dépôt http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial Release n'a pas de fichier Release.
W: Les données depuis un tel dépôt ne peuvent être authentifiées et sont donc potentiellement dangereuses à utiliser.
W: Voir les pages de manuel d'apt-secure(8) pour la création des dépôts et les détails de configuration d'un utilisateur.
E: http://ppa.launchpad.net/moka/stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages is not (yet) available (403 Forbidden)
```

I apologize for the language, but oddly enough when I try to change the system language and recreate the issue, I get "Failed to obtain authorisation" instead of the repositories list.

Apparently, all repositories listed do not have 'Release' files. Could it be because of the Switch to 5.0 ? I'm currently running 0.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems here.

The first is that something has happened to your `http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu` repository as it has `loki` as the release codename when this should be `xenial`.

You will need to replace all instances of `loki` with `xenial` in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and the files within `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. See another of my answers here for more information: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/15236/9699

The second issue is you have some PPAs enabled that aren't compatible with loki or that don't exist anymore:

- `versable/elementary-update` is not loki compatible
- `moka/stable` doesn't exist anymore.

So removing both of those PPAs from your sources files should also help resolve this issue.