# Error when trying sudo apt-get update

Tags: updates, apt, repositories

I have the Hera OS 5.1. Now when I want to run sudo apt-get update I got the following errors. What can I do? Thanks in advance.

```
Err:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/djart/minidlna/ubuntu bionic Release                                  
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu hera Release          
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:18 http://co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hera Release                                               
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:19 http://co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hera-updates Release                                       
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu hera Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:21 http://co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hera-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 8, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.creator import DbCreator
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 11, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
E: El repositorio «http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter hera Release» no tiene un fichero de Publicación.
N: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto está deshabilitado por omisión.
N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.
E: El repositorio «http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hera-security Release» no tiene un fichero de Publicación.
N: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto está deshabilitado por omisión.
N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.
E: El repositorio «http://ppa.launchpad.net/djart/minidlna/ubuntu bionic Release» no tiene un fichero de Publicación.
N: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto está deshabilitado por omisión.
N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.
E: El repositorio «http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu hera Release» no tiene un fichero de Publicación.
N: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto está deshabilitado por omisión.
N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.
E: El repositorio «http://co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hera Release» no tiene un fichero de Publicación.
N: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto está deshabilitado por omisión.
N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.
E: El repositorio «http://co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hera-updates Release» no tiene un fichero de Publicación.
N: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto está deshabilitado por omisión.
N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.
E: El repositorio «http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu hera Release» no tiene un fichero de Publicación.
N: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto está deshabilitado por omisión.
N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.
E: El repositorio «http://co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hera-backports Release» no tiene un fichero de Publicación.
N: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto está deshabilitado por omisión.
N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

---

Still persist this:

```
Obj:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu bionic InRelease  
Traceback (most recent call last):                     
  File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 8, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.creator import DbCreator
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 11, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think most of the errors I got were fixed. Just I have a remaining one that added to my question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AppCentre fails to fetch updates; sudo apt update gives several errors](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/15234/appcentre-fails-to-fetch-updates-sudo-apt-update-gives-several-errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue seems to be caused by some obsolete / wrong repositories.

First one (http://ppa.launchpad.net/djart/minidlna/ubuntu) was not updated since 2014, and using it is a really bad idea. You can remove it safely with:
`sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:djart/minidlna`

For the next ones, you'll have to do some source.list editing, because they contain the name `hera` instead of `bionic`. To do this, open Files as Administrator (right-click the Files icon), go to `/etc/apt` and open the `sources.list` file in Code. Look for the repositories listed in the errors and replace `hera` with `bionic`. For example:
`[...]ubuntu hera Release` should become `[...]ubuntu bionic Release` and `[...]ubuntu hera-backports Release` should become `[...]ubuntu bionic-backports Release`.

You might have to look into the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` folder, for example the `elementary.list` file might contain the `http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu hera Release` ppa. If so, just like in the above case, replace h`hera` with `bionic`.

Save your changes and run a `sudo apt update` again, to see the changes. If error still persist, add them to your question.

SImilar issue described here: [help fixing winehq error : hera Release does not have a Release file](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/24574/help-fixing-winehq-error-hera-release-does-not-have-a-release-file/24576#24576)

Answer (score 0):

You've added PPAs to your system which have caused breakages. Remove the PPAs you've added by adding `--remove` to the command you used to add it.